# nltk.word_tokenize apply at path

Tags: python, nltk

**Hi, Is there a method to apply this code to my file path? instead of the sentence "And now something completely different"?**

```py
import nltk
text = nltk.word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
print(nltk.pos_tag(text))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a .txt file, you could just open and read the content of it.

`text.txt`

```
This file is for testing purposes.
```

`python file`

```py
import nltk

file = open("text.txt", "r")
for line in file:
  text = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
  print(nltk.pos_tag(text))
  # output
  # [('This', 'DT'), ('file', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('for', 'IN'), ('testing', 'VBG'), ('purposes', 'NNS'), ('.', '.')]
```

Comment: Thank you! The code is work! But if I wanted to find only the french words in the text is there a solution?

Comment: I don't think you could with just pure NLTK. And if I'm not mistaken, NLTK is build for english words, you need to find another NLTK packages for french words.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have sent you and email.

Comment: I think that is a way to use more lenguages

from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
from nltk.wsd import lesk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

# ['als', 'arb', 'cat', 'cmn', 'dan', 'eng', 'eus', 'fas',
# 'fin', 'fra', 'fre', 'glg', 'heb', 'ind', 'ita', 'jpn', 'nno',
# 'nob', 'pol', 'por', 'spa', 'tha', 'zsm']
lang='fra'

sent = TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize("Je voudrai essayer avec cette phrase")
synsets = [lesk(sent, w, 'n') for w in sent]
print(synsets)